# Redis Enterprise (sharding) reliable queue

Tags: architecture, redis, queue, software-design

I am working on a application where I think I need a queue. I already intend to use Redis Enterprise in the application so it makes sense to use Redis for the queue. Redis has some useful commands for a queue: https://redis.io/commands/rpoplpush#pattern-reliable-queue. I have producers that insert records and consumers that process and remove the records. I can easily make the producers and consumers scale horizontally. So at scale the bottleneck will be Redis because the queue can only be stored on a single shard. Is there a good way to distribute a queue across multiple shards? The only solution I can come up with would be to make multiple queues and somehow ensure each queue hashes to a different shard. But this would require the producers, consumers, and queue keys to be changed when Redis is resharded which isn't ideal.

I am intending to use the queue to batch insert records into a database. The producers are web servers receiving requests and generating records. But during peak traffic times the database would not be able to keep up with the rate of single row inserts. I can't just buffer the requests on the web servers because all of the buffered records would be lost when a web server fails. A Redis queue provides fault tolerance because of the replication. The consumers can pop multiple records off the queue before performing the insert to lessen the load on the database. But it won't scale enough. Is there a better Redis solution that I am missing? Or is Redis not a good fit?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

**Edit:**

I have starting creating a library using the method discussed with @Itamar Haber. Available here: https://github.com/fenichelar/BQueue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A single Redis data structure, such as a List, indeed can not be sharded. The first question that needs to be is asked is whether your scaling concerns are justified - a single Redis shard can easily perform 10s if not 100s of 1000s ops/sec, and that kind of throughput can go a long way.

Assuming a single key/data structure/shard isn't enough (throughput-wise) for your needs, your hunch of using multiple keys is indeed the way to go in order to scale horizontally.

> somehow ensure each queue hashes to a different shard

Actually, that's overdoing it a little IMO. The default hashing function is usually good enough, so if you pick a sane number of keys/queues (e.g. 10 or 42), most chances are you'll get a solid distribution of these across slots.

> But this would require the producers, consumers, and queue keys to be changed when Redis is resharded which isn't ideal.

I disagree. Firstly, you need to remember that resharding in particular and cluster topology changed in general, are quite rare. I'm not saying they don't happen, but they are usually planned and managed by people. Secondly, and more importantly, even if such changes take place and hash slots are shuttled across the shards, the chances of all/most/many of your queues ending on the same node are still very low (see above). Lastly, if indeed all your keys end up on a single shard, you can always reshuffle/migrate them manually afterwards in order to balance the load (very easy with Redis Enterprise's UI/CLI/API).

Most importantly, you do not need to change your key names, producers and/consumers.

Opinion: I think Redis is a great fit for an updates buffer in front of another db/storage that's slower and can't handle peaks.

Disclaimer: I work at Redis Labs, home of open source Redis and the provider of Redis Enterprise.

Comment: Cluster needs to handle 10,000 inserts/second. So at least 30,000 transactions (lpush, rpoplpush, lrem). And about 2,000,000 non queue related transactions/second.

Comment: Each queue really requires 2 queues. So with Redis Enterprise sharding do the 2 queues need to be named using curly braces to ensure they map to the same shard for rpoplpush to work?

Comment: Also, hoping to get started with Redis Enterprise in the next few weeks :)

Comment: So with having multiple queues I need to have a list of queues to distribute the load across. That means if I want to change the number of queues I need to update the code in my consumers and producers. Or I could use a Redis set to store the queues. But this would make another hot key problem. Also on queue removal I need to keep processing old records before removing the queue. Maybe a set of queues for the consumers and another set for the producers. And cache the sets on each client for a period of time to remove the hot key issue.

Comment: wrt througput - sounds sane. wrt curlies - that's right, in OSS and Enterprise. wrt Enterprise - feel free to contact our support if needed. wrt last comment - unclear to me, comments are a lousy way to communicate.

Comment: Thanks. I created a library given our discussion: https://github.com/fenichelar/BQueue. Need to add tests and test it but I think it is going to work.